# Android P2P Sockets issue

Tags: android, sockets, ip-address, p2p, wireless

I"m building a P2P wifi app that requires bidirectional communication between every connected device and a central "host" (I've already addressed the issue of forcing the host onto that device in particular).

I've run through the developer.android tutorials and gotten all I can from those, but my issue at the moment is that I can't seem to get the host's sockets to connect to the P2P client devices properly...

My application for my host side currently displays all of the phones that have "connected" to it (via the p2p connect command) and has the addresses of all of those devices displayed in a list view on screen.  These addresses are shown as IPV6(I think) addresses and are usually identical to the device's hard-coded MAC addresses, with one hex pair value changed.  Example: Device's MAC is AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF and host's address for that device shows as being AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:13 (or similar).

The client side at this point in the workflow is waiting for the server to send it a small packet via port 8000.

However, at this point, when I attempt to connect from the host to any client, it throws the exception "Host could not be resolved..." and lists the device's IP address I'm trying to connect to, which properly matches the expected address that is displayed on screen of the connected devices.

I believe my particular concern revolves around the following line of code:

```
socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(device.deviceAddress, 8000)), 5000);
```

Where device is the WifiP2pDevice that we are trying to connect to.  In particular, looking at the InetSocketAddress help page, it expects our "device address" to be in the form of a string of IPV4 or IPV6.  Is android's P2P "Device Address" really IPV6?  Or am I missing something else completely obvious?

EDIT: I have been properly informed that P2P addresses are not applicable in any shape or form to sockets.  The only way P2P sockets can be done this way in Android is:
1. Clients get the IP address of the group owner/server from the Broadcast receiver's P2PInfo object.
2. All of the clients connect to the server's ip using sockets.
3. As the server receives connections, the server can get the ip addresses from the client devices via the socket that is created for each client.
4. Once both parties have each others' IP addresses, proper bidirectional communication can be achieved.

Comment: have you got the following on ur clients? ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(yoursocketnumber);
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

Comment: I do have seversockets on each of my clients, as well as the accept command.

Comment: Instead of a MAC address you ĉould better use an ip address i think.

Comment: arent the addresses listed IpV6 addresses, not MAC addresses?

Comment: I wonder why you open server sockets on what you first call your clients. Why aren't you opening one ServerSocket on the Host and let your clients connect to the host using a -client- Socket?

Comment: As I stated, the eventual goal is bidirectional communication and this just happens to be which way it happens first.  To be specific, the end goal is to transfer one file on the host to many clients simultaneously, so the clients need to connect to the server first in order to receive a short packet containing a port and file size (in order to display progress)